# Delete records from multiple tables in Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, sql-delete, multiple-tables

Using the following data, I am attempting to delete matching records from both tables.

Fruits

ID  Value
1   Apple
2   Pear
3   Banana
4   Grape

Animals

ID  Value
1   Bear
2   Monkey
3   Apple
4   Pig

There is no defined relationship between these two tables.

Since "Apple" appears in both tables, I would like to remove this record from each of them.

I've tried the following query to accomplish this:

```
DELETE DISTINCTROW Animals.*, Fruits.*
FROM Animals INNER JOIN Fruits ON Animals.Value = Fruits.Value;
```

However, when I run this, I receive the following error:

> Could not delete from specified tables.

What am I doing wrong, and what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without establishing a relationship to take advantage of a cascading delete, you're out of luck. The DELETE statement works on one table at a time (with cascading deletes, if any, carried out behind the scenes). You have no choice but to devise something to accomplish what you want. Perhaps, via a Macro, one could do something simplistic like this:

```
UPDATE Animals, Fruits SET Animals.Value="DELETED", Fruits.Value="DELETED" WHERE Animals.Value=Fruits.Value
DELETE Animals WHERE Animals.Value="DELETED"
DELETE Fruits WHERE Fruits.Value="DELETED"
```

Short of making a sophisticated VBA macro (and perhaps a temporary table), this is about as good as it gets.

As an aside, I don't believe it could be done even with a more heavy duty DB such as SQL Server or DB2; a DELETE upon a subquery or view still requires that the DB system can resolve it to a particular table.

I'm gonna guess that the error you got is a matter of locked rows (as a result of the INNER JOIN).

Comment: I don't know of any DBMS that can do this in a single statement (barring cascading deletes or triggers, which are different forms of follow-on effects, not properly part of the statement).